# How can I sort the results reported in the description?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a python code that checks the time differences between one match and another as long as it is in the same championship and on the same day.

The results I hoped for were successful, setting a minimum difference between them of 90 minutes.

However, now I would like to sort the results among themselves and with the all() function I would like to receive a total report among them... let me explain better

**data.json**

```
[
  {
    "Day": "Giornata 29",
    "Matches": {
      "Home": "Egnatia",
      "Away": "Kukesi",
      "Times": "19.03. 15:00",
      "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024"
    }
  },
  {
    "Day": "Giornata 29",
    "Matches": {
      "Home": "Egnatia",
      "Away": "Kukesi",
      "Times": "20.03. 16:09",
      "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024"
    }
  },
  {
    "Day": "Giornata 41",
    "Matches": {
      "Home": "Lincoln",
      "Away": "Leyton Orient",
      "Times": "19.03. 16:00",
      "Championship": "CALCIO\nINGHILTERRA League One\n2023/2024"
    }
  },
  {
    "Day": "Giornata 30",
    "Matches": {
      "Home": "Napoli",
      "Away": "Atalanta",
      "Times": "30.03. 12:30",
      "Championship": "CALCIO\nITALIA Serie A\n2023/2024"
    }
  }
]
```

**code.py**

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta 
import json

with open('data.json', 'r+') as f:
    fileData = json.load(f)

i = 1

minutes = 90

limits = timedelta(minutes=minutes)

try:
    for x in range(len(fileData)):
        if fileData[i]['Day'] == fileData[x]['Day'] and fileData[i]['Matches']['Championship'] ==
fileData[x]['Matches']['Championship']:
        
            calculate = datetime.strptime(fileData[i]['Matches']['Times'], '%d.%m. %H:%M') -
datetime.strptime(fileData[x]['Matches']['Times'], '%d.%m. %H:%M')

            calculator = timedelta(seconds=calculate.seconds)
            #print(calculator)
            if calculator > limits:
        
                print(f'''
    {fileData[x]["Matches"]["Championship"]} {fileData[x]["Day"]}
    {fileData[x]["Matches"]["Home"]} - {fileData[x]["Matches"]["Away"]}
    {calculate}
    {fileData[i]["Matches"]["Home"]} - {fileData[i]["Matches"]["Away"]} 
                 ''')
            i += 1
        else:
            i += 1
        #i += 1 
 except:
    pass
```

I receive the print I request with the minimum minute difference and all the correct instructions.

now I would like to add up how many matches in a day of a given championship satisfy the time distance shown above, if all the matches of that day have a minimum difference from each other of at least 90 minutes, it prints the matches for me day and the championship, otherwise it print "False" messages to me if a championship day does not have all the matches with a time difference between them.

**I expect an output like this:**

```
"Name Championship"
"Number Day (example 1)" 2/3
"Number Day (example 2)" 3/3
"Number Day (example 3)" 1/3
```

**to be continued...**

what I mean is 2/3 for example, it means that it adds the matches of that day and that championship, the value is:

match with a distance of at least 90 minutes/match without distance of those 90 minutes

I don't know setdefault and defaultdict perfectly, I searched on the internet and came across several tutorials, but none of them satisfied the answer to my question, I'll start by saying that I'm new to Python and I've been running into this problem for 2 days... Thanks so much in advance to anyone who helps me <3

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to check for each `Championship`, check for the groups of rows that have the same `Day`, then check if a match has any other matches within 90 minutes of it.

Then output how many matches are within 90 minutes out of the total matches for each `Championship` for each `Day`.

If I understood correctly, this is what I did. I utilized `pandas` to do the work for me:

```
import json
import pandas as pd



# Correcting the datetime parsing issue and evaluating time differences accurately
def time_distance_evaluation(df, timeDiff):
    # Correcting the date format for datetime parsing
    df[['Date', 'Time']] = df['Matches.Times'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
    df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M')

    # Reset the 'Less_Than_90_Min' column to False
    df[f'Less_Than_{timeDiff}_Min'] = False

    # Group by Championship and Day
    for (championship, day), group in df.groupby(['Matches.Championship', 'Day']):
        # For each match in the group
        for index, row in group.iterrows():
            # Compare with every other row in the same group
            for _, other_row in group.drop(index).iterrows():
                # Calculate time difference in minutes
                time_diff = abs((row['Time'] - other_row['Time']).total_seconds() / 60)
                # Check if the difference is less than 90 minutes
                if time_diff < {timeDiff}:
                    df.at[index, f'Less_Than_{timeDiff}_Min'] = True
                    break

    return df

with open('data.json', 'r+') as f:
    fileData = json.load(f)
df = pd.json_normalize(fileData)

timeDiff = 90
df_with_check = time_distance_evaluation(df, timeDiff)





# PRINT RESULTS
# We will group by 'Matches.Championship' and 'Day', then calculate the desired metrics
results = df_with_check.groupby(['Matches.Championship', 'Day']).agg(
    Total=(f'Less_Than_{timeDiff}_Min', 'size'),
    True_Count=(f'Less_Than_{timeDiff}_Min', 'sum') 
    ).reset_index()

# Format and print the results
for _, row in results.iterrows():
    match = row["Matches.Championship"].replace("\n","")
    print(f'{match}')
    print(f'{row["Day"]} {row["True_Count"]}/{row["Total"]}\n')
```

**Output:**

```
CALCIOALBANIA Super League2023/2024
Giornata 29 2/2

CALCIOINGHILTERRA League One2023/2024
Giornata 41 0/1

CALCIOITALIA Serie A2023/2024
Giornata 30 0/1
```

Comment: Perfect! do you have a simpler solution? I'm new to python

Comment: That is a pretty simple solution. I'll add comments in there so you can see how it's working. Familiarize yourself with pandas too. Really powerful package to do data manipulation, data clesning, etc.

Comment: A thousand thanks! Unfortunately I have never used Panda, so I feel lost for this reason